# How to scroll page and scrape site?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

from another thread I was suggested to specify this question on another topic.
My issue is related to scraping a website that requires to scroll down the page dynamically and in the meanwhile copy the data in my dataframe.

Until now with the code below I can copy only the first elements in the page because they are the visible ones, but I need the whole list until the end of the page

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,30)
driver.get('https://www.livescore.com/en/')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
games = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class = "MatchRow_matchRowWrapper__1BtJ3"]')
data1 = []
for game in games:
    data1.append({
        'Home':game1.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[contains(@class,"MatchRow_home")]').text,
        'Away':game1.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[contains(@class,"MatchRow_away")]').text,
        'Time':game1.find_element(By.XPATH, './/span[contains(@id,"match-row")]').text
    })
    df = pd.DataFrame(data1)  # create dataframe
print(df)
```

Any tips?
THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My tip is get the data from the api. Far more efficient than using Selenium here:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import datetime

url = "https://prod-public-api.livescore.com/v1/api/react/date/soccer/20220309/0.00?MD=1"
jsonData = requests.get(url).json()

rows = []
for stage in jsonData['Stages']:
    events = stage['Events']
    for event in events:
        gameDateTime = event['Esd']
        date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(gameDateTime), '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
        gameTime = date_time_obj.strftime("%H:%M")
        homeTeam = event['T1'][0]['Nm']
        awayTeam = event['T2'][0]['Nm']
        
        row = {
            'Home':homeTeam,
            'Away':awayTeam,
            'Time':gameTime}
        rows.append(row)
        
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
                Home                 Away  Time
0    Manchester City          Sporting CP  20:00
1        Real Madrid  Paris Saint-Germain  20:00
2           FC Porto                 Lyon  17:45
3         Real Betis  Eintracht Frankfurt  17:45
4          Dundee FC           St. Mirren  19:45
..               ...                  ...    ...
281       Modafen FK           Cankaya FK  11:00
282          UPDF FC         Arua Hill SC  11:00
283    Wakiso Giants         Mbarara City  13:00
284      Kokand 1912              Olympic  13:30
285     Nasaf Qarshi    Metallurg Bekobod  13:30

[286 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Hi @chitown88, your answer is perfect. An additional question, would be possibile to put inside the dataframe only the current live matches, not all of them, with the current minute of game?

Comment: So only live games?

Comment: Yes, if possible with the current minute of game

Comment: can you add a new question and I'll put the solution up there?